# 2d array manipulation in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array in the following format:

```
export const dataBubble = [
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0],
  [0, 2, 0],
  [0, 3, 0],
  [0, 4, 0],
  [0, 5, 0],
  [0, 6, 0],
  [0, 7, 0],
  [0, 8, 0],
  [0, 9, 0],
  [0, 10, 0],
  [1, 0, 6],
  [1, 1, 8],
  [1, 2, 5],
  [1, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 1],
  [1, 5, 4],
  [1, 6, 5],
  [1, 7, 5],
  [1, 8, 4],
  [1, 9, 3],
  [1, 10, 9],
  [2, 0, 5],
  [2, 1, 5],
  [2, 2, 5],
  [2, 3, 6],
  [2, 4, 8],
  [2, 5, 7],
  [2, 6, 8],
  [2, 7, 5],
  [2, 8, 4],
  [2, 9, 2],
  [2, 10, 8],
  [3, 0, 9],
  [3, 1, 5],
  [3, 2, 9],
  [3, 3, 8],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [3, 5, 4],
  [3, 6, 2],
  [3, 7, 5],
  [3, 8, 7],
  [3, 9, 6],
  [3, 10, 3],
  [4, 0, 7],
  [4, 1, 3],
  [4, 2, 9],
  [4, 3, 5],
  [4, 4, 11],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [4, 6, 7],
  [4, 7, 6],
  [4, 8, 4],
  [4, 9, 4],
  [4, 10, 5],
  [5, 0, 1],
  [5, 1, 3],
  [5, 2, 6],
  [5, 3, 8],
  [5, 4, 5],
  [5, 5, 5],
  [5, 6, 4],
  [5, 7, 8],
  [5, 8, 9],
  [5, 9, 2],
  [5, 10, 4],
  [6, 0, 2],
  [6, 1, 1],
  [6, 2, 0],
  [6, 3, 3],
  [6, 4, 8],
  [6, 5, 5],
  [6, 6, 6],
  [6, 7, 2],
  [6, 8, 5],
  [6, 9, 6],
  [6, 10, 4],
  [7, 0, 1],
  [7, 1, 0],
  [7, 2, 5],
  [7, 3, 0],
  [7, 4, 5],
  [7, 5, 8],
  [7, 6, 9],
  [7, 7, 0],
  [7, 8, 7],
  [7, 9, 8]
];
```

We need to reverse the array elements based on the first two elements of the inner array, such that the resultant array becomes:

```
[
[0,10,0],
[0,9,0],
[0,8,0],
[0,7,0],
[0,6,0],
[0,5,0],
[0,4,0],
[0,3,0],
[0,2,0],
[0,1,0],
[1,10,9],
[1,9,3],
[1,8,4],
[1,7,5],
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
[7,0,1]
```

I use this in a react js project, so is there anyway we can use the JS map function of an array to do it? If not what will be the optimal solution?

Comment: There is not enough information here: are the values limited to some range? The first value in the subarrays seems to be between 0 and 7, and the second value between 0 and 10? Such constraints may determine which solution to propose.

Comment: The subarrays second value may vary but first value will always be 0 to 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your second value is guaranteed to be less than an amount (for example I assumed 1000 in this case) then you can do this:

```
dataBubble.sort((x, y) => (x[0] - y[0])*1000 + y[1] - x[1]);
```

Basically we sum them up, but give the first element a higher coefficient, thus making it the primary sorter.

Otherwise, you need to involve an if check:

```
dataBubble.sort((x, y) => {
  if(x[0] == y[0]) {
    return y[1] - x[1];
  } else {
    return x[0] - y[0];
  }
});
```

If you return a negative value from the sort function, JS will put `x` before `y`. Otherwise it will put `x` after `y`.

1. If `x[0]` and `y[0]` are equal, we need to sort depending on `x[1]` and `y[1]`. `y[1] - x[1]` will be negative if `x[1]` is larger, therefore if `x[1]` is larger `x` will come before `y`.
2. If `x[0]` and `y[0]` are different we need to sort based on them. `x[0] - y[0]` will be negative if `x[0]` is smaller, therefore if `x[0]` is smaller, `x` will come before `y`.

Comment: The first solution will also work fine in this scenario, consider it as a scale of x axis in a graph with interval 1.